# How can I make two JS Splice work together

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two splice methods that work as expected but only if I have one at a time

```
const prev = [
    [135,136,137,138,139],
    [275,276,277,278,279],
];

const after = [
    [141,142,143,144,145],
    [281,282,283,284,285],
];

scrollFrom.splice(0, 0, 135,136,137,138,139);
```

I get:

```
[135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140 ...]
```

If I only have:

```
(...)
scrollFrom.splice(1, 0, ...after[0]);
```

I will get:

```
[140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145 ...]
```

However if I have both splice functions, like this:

```
(...)
scrollFrom.splice(0, 0, ...prev[0]);
scrollFrom.splice(1, 0, ...after[0]);
```

The result is this:

```
[135, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140 ... ]
```

What I would like to obtain is this:

```
[135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145 ... ]
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong or other solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe a `.sort()` after?

Comment: `scrollFrom.slice(0, 0, 135,136,137,138,139);` <== Is that meant to be **`splice`** rather than `slice`?

Comment: Where does 140 come from? It's not in any of the source array's you've listed.

Comment: The second `splice` should acount for all the elements that have already been inserter from `prev[0]`. It shouldn't splice from `1`, it should splice from `prev[0].length + 1` like so: `scrollFrom.splice(prev[0].length + 1, 0, ...after[0]);`

Comment: What does `scrollFrom` contain initially?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're not allowing for the items you've already inserted. You're using index 1 for the second `splice`, but `prev` has more than one entry in it. Insted:

```
scrollFrom.splice(0, 0, ...prev[0]);
scrollFrom.splice(prev[0].length, 0, ...after[0]);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
const prev = [
    [135,136,137,138,139],
    [275,276,277,278,279],
];

const after = [
    [141,142,143,144,145],
    [281,282,283,284,285],
];

const scrollFrom = []; // Or whatever

scrollFrom.splice(0, 0, ...prev[0]);
scrollFrom.splice(prev[0].length, 0, ...after[0]);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

console.log(scrollFrom);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: `prev[0].length + scrollFromInitialLength` to be sure (in case that `140` and whatever else is already in there)

Comment: ... I guess `scrollFrom.unshift(...prev[0]); `scrollFrom.push(...after[0])` is better for that matter (inspired by your other answer :D).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - I don't think so (on the `scrollFromInitialLength` thing), the OP is inserting at the beginning of the array. On `unshift` - Yeah, could do: `scrollFrom.unshift(...prev, ...after);` :-)

Comment: `scrollFrom.splice(1` and the names of the arrays suggest the opposite.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - For me, the `1` implied wanting to insert after what `prev` has (`after` comes *after* `prev`). But I could see another interpretation, too. Really, the OP needs to provide much more solid information.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't taking into consideration that the indexes of the array increase with the first splice, duh!

```
            scrollFrom.splice(0, 0, ...prev[0]);
            scrollFrom.splice(6, 0, ...after[0]);
```

This returns: `[135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, ...]` perfect!

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: That hardcoded `6` in the second splice may result in further problems. Would you please show us the initial content of `scrollFrom` so we can give you a better answer

Comment: indeed, it will be inserted inside a for loop and use it's index

Answer (score 0):

When calling the second `splice`, you should account for the items inserted using the first `splice`. So instead of splicing from `1` you should splice from after the last element:

```
let initialLength = scrollFrom.length;                                  // cache the initial length of 'scrollFrom' in case it is not equal to 1 (contains 0 or more than 1 elements)
scrollFrom.splice(0, 0, ...prev[0]);                                    // insert elements from `prev[0]` at the begining of the array
scrollFrom.splice(prev[0].length + initialLength, 0, ...after[0]);      // insert elements from `after[0]` at the "new end" which is after the newly added elements and the already existing elements
```

Or better yet, use `unshift` to insert the `prev[0]` elements and `push` to insert `after[0]` elements like so:

```
scrollFrom.unshift(...prev[0]);
scrollFrom.push(...after[0]);
```

`unshift` will insert the new elements before the already existing elements of `scrollFrom`, whereas `push` will instert them after.